# How to insert large number of nodes into Neo4J

Tags: graph, neo4j, nodes, traceroute

I need to insert about 1 million of nodes in Neo4j. I need to specify that each node is unique, so every time I insert a node it has to be checked that there's not the same node yet. Also the relationships must be unique.

I'm using Python and Cypher:

```
uq = 'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:ipNode8) ASSERT a.ip IS UNIQUE'
...
queryProbe = 'MERGE (a:ipNode8 {ip:"' + prev + '"})'
...
queryUpdateRelationship= 'MATCH (a:ipNode8 {ip:"' + prev + '"}),(b:ipNode8 {ip:"' + next + '"}) MERGE (a)-[:precede]->(b)'
```

The problem is that after putting 40-50K nodes into Neo4j , the insertion speed slows down quickly and I can not to put anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite open ended. In addition to @InverseFalcon's recommendations, here are some other things you can investigate to speed things up.

1. Read the Performance Tuning documentation, and follow the recommendations. In particular, you might be running into memory-related issues, so the [Memory Tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#memory-tuning) section may be very helpful.
2. Your Cypher query(ies) can probably be sped up. For instance, if it makes sense, you can try something like the following. The `data` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters) is expected to be a list of objects having the format `{a: 123, b: 234}`. You can make the list as long as appropriate (e.g., 20K) to avoid running out of memory on the server while it processes the list within a single transaction. (This query assumes that you also want to create `b` if it does not exist.)

   ```
   UNWIND {data} AS d
   MERGE (a:ipNode8 {ip: d.a})
   MERGE (b:ipNode8 {ip: d.b})
   MERGE (a)-[:precede]->(b)
   ```

   There are also [periodic execution](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management_and_periodic_execution) APOC procedures that you might be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

For mass inserts like this, it's best to use [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) with periodic commit or the [import tool](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/).

I believe it's also best practice to use a parameterized query instead of appending values into a string.

Also, you created a unique property constraint on :ipNode8, but not :ipNode, which is the first one you MERGE. Seems like you'll need a unique constraint for that one too.